# Testdisk is not recognizing a linux directory; How do I fix it?

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery, file-permissions, testdisk

About a week ago, my "Downloads/" directory very suddenly showed as being empty. I ran testdisk, and at first, it was able to read the files as still being on the actual disk. However, when I moved stuff from my "Documents" folder onto another disk to do some moving-around, suddenly, testdisk hasn't been able to read the "Downloads" folder at all. In testdisk's "Analyze" option, it reads as:

```
-rw-------
```

instead of

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

like it's supposed to, even though, when I'm in the terminal and I run

```
sudo su
ls -lhd ~/Downloads/
```

it shows the way it's supposed to. A supporting screenshot:

[testdisk screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ1mN.png)

How can I fix it in testdisk so that it can open the Downloads folder and list the files so that I can recover them?

Comment: When rescuing files from any media, do not WRITE to the media. MOVE = Copy, then Delete original -> where Delete = WRITE to disk to mark file as deleted. If you DO write, there might be problems to do further recovery of files.

Comment: The only truly SAFE option you have when a filesystem is in a damaged state is to recover as many files as possible, then either replace the disk or possibly verify its function by at least by reformatting using the "overwrite with zeros"-option. If that turns up with ANY faults, I'd unconditionally replace the disk.

Comment: The thing about that is that I'd already run `smartctl --all /dev/sda`, and it reported back saying that the disk was perfectly fine.

Comment: smartctl will not catch ALL possible faults, i.e. you have no guarantees.

Comment: Is my Downloads/ folder totally screwed now?

Comment: My opinion: The ENTIRE DISK is in an unknown state. Copy off all data you wish to keep, reformat at least - as I said above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you moved or deleted your Downloads directory, and subsequently tried to move or copy a file to Downloads.

You can reproduce this easily enough (with a different directory, such as `example`) like this

```
mkdir example
cp /etc/hosts example    # Copies "hosts" to "example/hosts"

mv example /tmp          # Ooops
cp /etc/hosts example    # Copies "hosts" to the file "example"
```

I'd simply remove the `Downloads` file and recreate the directory

```
rm Downloads
mkdir Downloads
```

If the directory is still on your system you can hunt for the missing Downloads directory with a `find` command like this

```
find / -type d -name Downloads
```

but I suspect that "*when I moved stuff from my "Documents" folder onto another disk*" you inadvertently moved `Downloads` too.